# #1265 Data truncated for column 'costo_total_unidad' at row 1 Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'costo_total_unidad' at row 1

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, decimal

i don't understand why i have this error in my phpmyadmin.

This error pop up when i try to create an register in my DB.

costo_total_unidad, DECIMAL(4,2) NOT NULL;

I insert data like: 123,43 or 3211,50, and i even try with 123.43 or 3211.50 but it's the same problem.

## 1265 Data truncated for column 'costo_total_unidad' at row 1 Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'costo_total_unidad' at row 1

But in my register appears like: 99.99

Can someone explain me why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because `DECIMAL(4,2)` means that you have space for 4 digits total, with 2 for fractional part - leaving 2 for integer part. That's why you can store only 99.99 as the highest value. If you want to store numbers up to 9999.99, you need `DECIMAL(6,2)`. And as usual, [it's all in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html)..

Comment: Many Thanks, sorry i know it's in the manual but it's hard to understand it for my english, but well thanks!